# handling net socket response on restify js

Tags: node.js, sockets, promise, restify

I'm writing a middleware in nodeJs with restify, but I can't handle the async response from the server:

the following code is called here in my index.js:

```
 app.get('/get-users', [getUsers]);
 ...

 function getUsers(req, res) {
    var query = {type:'get-users', parameters:{}, content:[]};
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var queryJson = JSON.stringify(query);
    var message = queryJson+"\n";
    res.send(client.writeToServer(message));
   }
```

the function writeToServer is in a separate file called mySocket.js:

```
  var net = require('net');
  var host = '127.0.0.1';
  var port = 6011;
  var response;
  var client;

  var Promise = require('promise');

  client = net.connect(port, host); 
  client.setEncoding("utf8");

  client.on('connect', function() {
     console.log('Connected');
  });


function getPromisedData(message) {
  if( client.write(message))
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                       console.log('calling client.once');
                       client.once('data', function(data) {
                           console.log('once.data logging: '+JSON.parse(data));
                           response = JSON.parse(data);
                           resolve(response); });
              });     
}

exports.writeToServer = function (message) {
   console.log('\nwriteToServer');
   getPromisedData(message).then(function(response) {
      console.log('promise resolved with response: '+response);
      return response;});
   }
```

tried but doesn't work. here's the output:

```
Connected

writeToServer
calling client.once
once.data logging: 
promise resolved with response:
```

am I missing something?

thanks in advance,
Morgan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a promises expert, but I can see a couple of possible issues here. First, you should always use curly braces to enclose everything that comes after an if statement.

```
function getPromisedData(message) {
    if( client.write(message)) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                   console.log('calling client.once');
                   client.once('data', function(data) {
                       console.log('once.data logging: '+JSON.parse(data));
                       response = JSON.parse(data);
                       resolve(response); });
        }); 
    }
}
```

Second, when you call res.send it writes back to the requestor immediately. You haven't waited for your client.writeToServer call to return anything. writeToServer should probably return a promise as well so you could do something like this:

```
client.writeToServer(message).then(function(server_reponse){
    res.send(server_response);
    next();
}
```

Frankly, I would ditch the promises and use callbacks until you have a good grasp on what is going on.